# Не могу понять ,как все условия добавить

Tags: python

Напишите функцию is_valid_pin_codes, которая будет принимать в качестве параметра список этих пин-кодов — строка из четырех цифр, и возвращать логическое значение — валидный список или нет. Убедитесь в том, что среди этих пин-кодов в списке не будет дубликатов, все они хранятся в виде строк, их длина равна 4 символам и содержат они только цифры.

Пример аргумента для функции is_valid_pin_codes:

['1101', '9034', '0011']
Если список удовлетворяет всем поставленным условиям, функция возвращает логическое значение True. Если хоть одно из условий нарушено, возвращаемое значение — False. Предусмотреть проверку на пустой список в аргументе функции и вернуть False.
Вот мой код:

```
def is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes):
    for x in pin_codes:
        if pin_codes.count(x) < 1 and len(x) == 4 and pin_codes.isnumeric():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша идея была верной. Исполнение должно быть улучшено.

1. проверка счета - на равенство.
2. проверка типа - на строку.
3. выход с `False` при пустой строке или первом же несовпадении и нормальное завершение с `True`.

```
def is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes):
    if not len (pin_codes):
        return False
    for x in pin_codes:
        if not (pin_codes.count(x) == 1 and type(x) == str and len(x) == 4):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое,там еще добавил x.isnumeric()),так как строка должна быть только из цифр

Comment: for x in pin_codes:
        if (
            pin_codes.count(x) > 1
            and not type(x) == str
            and not len(x) == 4
            and not x.isnumeric()
        ):
            return False
    return True
а почему такой код не подходит?

Comment: Подходит, только не and, а or. `not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B)`